# Ajax remove row from grid

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to Ajax but I want to delete a row from the grid with ajax.
The code below doesn't work. Could you give me some insights?

Whenever the checkbox is checked then it must delete the row.

```
@Html.Grid(Model.RequestList.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate)).Columns(c => {
    c.Add().Titled("View").Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(30).RenderValueAs(p => Html.CheckBox("checkedz",(int)p.Status==1?true:false,new {@class="aaa",onclick="aaa('"+p.Id+"')" }));
})
.WithPaging(20).Selectable(false)

function aaa(id) {
    var idyus = id;
    var chbox = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Remove", "Request", new { Area = "Options" })',
        success: function () {
            chbox.parent().parent().remove();
            console.log("success");
        }
    });
}

public ActionResult Remove(Guid? Id)
{
    if (!Id.HasValue)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    _requestService.Remove(Id.Value);
    _requestService.Save();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: *it doesn't work*, what doesn't work? Do you get any errors? Can you please provide more details and if there's any error messages you're getting can you post them too. Also you're not sending `idyus` to your backend code via ajax, is this a typo?

Comment: Specify `data` attribute in ajax call.

Comment: my chbox is not working, how can i find clicked chbox?

Comment: Your  `Remove` method is not enabled for POST and your ajax call is not sending any data to the server.